# Is there software to mirror a Windows PC via AirPlay?

Tags: windows, appletv, airplay

I would like to mirror my Windows PC to my Apple TV via AirPlay. I've found a few options which enable Windows Media Player to receive video via AirPlay. I've also found an application named Airfoil which allows you to stream audio from Windows. I know that the [beta of Mountain Lion supports AirPlay mirroring](http://9to5mac.com/2012/02/16/airplay-mirroring-in-os-x-mountain-lion-from-the-board-room-to-the-living-room-and-beyond/), but is there a Windows option?

Comment: Apple generally considers AirPlay a proprietary technology - anything outside iTunes on Windows will most likely need to use something else than AirPlay.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not sure I understand your comment. iTunes is software used to manage iOS devices and purchase music. AirPlay is used to stream music / video from iOS and Mac OS computers. Am I missing something?

Comment: ITunes supports AirPlay.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I thought iTunes only supported AirPlay for audio.....

Comment: iTunes can send video to AppleTV using AirPlay.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen but not mirroring. Ie I can play a video from iTunes but I cannot mirror my desktop or an application.

Comment: Hence my wording " anything outside iTunes on Windows will most likely need to use something else than AirPlay"...  Is it clearer now?

Comment: Airparrot works on a pc also, not only mac

Comment: This program is questionable but claims to work: https://www.5kplayer.com/airplay/5kplayer-apple-tv-mirroring.htm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use a program called [AirParrot](http://airparrot.com/) to mirror my Windows PC to my Apple TV (third generation). There is also a version that works on Macs.

<sub>Note that the ability to mirror a Mac to an AppleTV is a new feature of OS X Mountain Lion.</sub>

Comment: LonelyScreen work for me on Windows 7 64bit, http://www.lonelyscreen.com/download.html , and I comment it here as an alternative solution.

Comment: +1 for lonelyscreen from iOS to PC. Performance not as good as AirCast and doesn't have options, but it works. I noticed some lag with lonelyscreen, but for free and used in a presentation environment where you're doing not show high frames streaming video or audio, should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this indirectly if you have an iPad.

Install remote control software on the iPad (e.g. [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile.aspx)) that controls your PC and then use airplay mirroring to display the iPad's screen onto your apple tv.

How effective this is will depend upon the type of content you wish to mirror, video is not going to work but static content may be OK.